# False enconding, e.g. Ã¤

Tags: php, format

I load the data from an html-document via

```
  header('Content-Type: …;charset=utf-8');  
  $html = file($link);
```

When I echo the data I get this output

```
KindertagesstÃ¤tte
```

But the Ã¤ should be an Ä ...

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your html page is likely to be encoded with either ANSI or ISO-8859

On your php page :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

On the HTML page you are trying to link you should also check the encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: If both encoding are not the same it could result in error just like yours

Answer (score 0):

try php iconv (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

**example:**

```
<?php

echo iconv("your character set", "UTF-8", $html);

?>
```